# Put the words in the correct order to make sentence

Tags: sentence-construction

the words are the following

cat's / operated/this/My/ being/on/afternoon

I construct this sentence by this way

My cat's being operated on this afternoon.

I am not 100% sure this is correct and this kind of constructions seems strange to me, but that is the only option I could make up.
Could you please take a look and provide second opinion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that is correct. Alternatively, I could say "that's correct," because the apostrophe-s is a contraction for "is," just like "cat's" here is a contraction for "cat is." It's not formal, but it is correct.

> My **cat's** being operated on this afternoon.
>
> My **cat is** being operated on this afternoon.

You could also say "My cat is having an operation this afternoon," or "My cat is having surgery this afternoon."

Comment: I am confused because of ON this afternoon? is this common

Comment: @THEGreatGatsby "operated on" not "on this afternoon" 
 https://www.thefreedictionary.com/operate+on#:~:text=Verb,failed%20to%20save%20his%20life%22